# how to get upstream project info on a downstream project - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, post-build-event

In Jenkins, if we use Post-Build Trigger to start another build

What are ENVs available to the new build.

I need to identify, parent builds Name, Build Number, Last Successful Artifacts' URL  etc.,

In simple words, how to get upstream project info on a downstream project

Is that possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to pass variables from one build to the next. It is used in much the same way as the Post Build Trigger plugin you mentioned you're using already.

It defines some variables that are passed through to the next job, but you are free to define your own in the box provided, e.g:

```
ARTEFACT_URL=www.example.com/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER #using another variable from this build
SOMETHING=VALUE
UPSTREAM_BUILD_NAME=myProject
UPSTREAM_BUILD_NUMBER=$BUILD_NUMBER 
#note that you shouldn't override any properties likely to be set in subsequent builds!
```

Comment: -1: This solution means you have to explicitly pass all these parameters from all upstream jobs to all downstream jobs, which is rather cumbersome. There should be a more generic way of doing it.

Comment: That would be ideal. It seems to me things like name of parent project, parent project's workspace path, parent build number, parent trigger, etc. would be straightforward additions. Plus, it wouldn't depend on you having permissions to alter the parent project.

Comment: You may be able to use $JOB_NAME in the upstream project, when triggering the downstream project with this plugin.

Comment: It does not solve use cases where I don't even want the upstream project to know it has a downstream project and don't want the upstream project to make the downstream job inoperable